# Flyway wrongly load and execute migration definitions of "each ejb module" of deployed ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, flyway

I'm facing a strange problem, I've a JEE7 application with some ejb modules, in each ejb module I've a set of flyway sql migrations (my app runs on glassfish 4.0.1).

When I create a new sql migration in the first ejb module (under src/main/resources/db/migration) the other modules try to execute the new sql migration (but this new migration is not present into the other ejb modules !!!).

Seems like that flyway try to load a list of all migrations that it finds on "db/migration" resource and wrongly collects migrations of all ejb modules into the ear intead to load the migration of the given ejb module...

Example:

ear with 2 modules:

```
ejb module 1
ejb module 2
```

ejb module 1 migrations:

```
V1.00.20142912191315__create_tables.sql (BASELINE)
V1.00.20150108173546__new_fields_and_tables.sql (PENDING)
```

ejb module 2 migrations:

```
V1.00.20142912191315__create_tables.sql (BASELINE)
```

when I redeploy the ear, the migration V1.00.20150108173546__new_fields_and_tables.sql of ejb module 1 was successfully executed but the ejb module 2 wrongly try to run the same migration V1.00.20150108173546__new_fields_and_tables.sql present on ejb module 1...

I can't understand why this happens and how to solve this issue.

Can anyone help me ?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue simply putting the migration of every EJB module on  separated folder ex.:

- ejb module 1: migration definitions into db.migration.module1 folder
- ejb module 2: migration definitions into db.migration.module2 folder
- and so on...

then specifying on every ejb module where to load the migration definitions via flyway "locations" property ex.:

- ejb module1: flyway.setLocations("db/migration/module1");
- ejb module2: flyway.setLocations("db/migration/module2");
- and so on...

So I can have multiple ejb into one ear and every ejb loads and runs the owned migrations...

Hope this helps to anyone...

Cheers.

PS: thanks to Eddy Gasparotto for his valuable help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Flyway by default uses the context class loader, which in your case appears to have visibility over all EJB modules. You can specify a different (module-specific) class loader using `Flyway.setClassLoader()` to restrict the scanning to only the resources visible to that one.

Comment: Thanks Axel probably you're right but I don't understand what to set to bypass the problem, I've tried to set flyway.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); or flyway.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()); but the problem is still there, can you drive me into the right direction ?

Comment: Seems that when I've an EAR with multiple EJB modules that modules have EAR classpath visibility so flyway loads the migration definitions from every db/migration folder defined in each EJB module, I can't understand how to bypass that problem, can you help me ?

Comment: I believe this is a question for a GlassFish expert, which I'm not.